# how to understand Black-Scholes volatility is average of local volatilities

Tags: local-volatility

> Black-Scholes volatility is average of local volatilities.

It is from:
https://bookdown.org/maxime_debellefroid/MyBook/all-about-volatility.html

First what's the meaning of `the average of all the paths between spot and the maturity and strike of the option`? Here does `path` mean the underlying path satisfying
$$S_0=\text{Spot}\rightarrow S_T=\text{Strike}?$$
and does average means for each time $T',$ the BS implied vol
$$\sigma_{BS}(T',K) = average\Big[\sigma_{local}(S_i(T'))|S_i(0)=\text{Spot},S_i(T)=K\Big]?$$
here $i$ is the index of i-th path.
And I saw the similar result that local vol is the average of forward instantaneous vol:
$$\sigma^2(K,T)=E[\sigma^2_T|S_T=K],$$
do they say the same thing?

Also how to understand `ATM volatility is the same for both Black-Scholes and Local Volatility`?

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is a *path*? The picture is helpful, it shown three different paths, in red. Of course there is an infinite number of paths between two endpoints, not just three.

Comment: @nbbo2 what's the value of x-axis? time to maturity? I confused with right-down side labels (`high local volatility`). Seems it is the path of underlying price what I said above

Comment: @nbbo2 could I understand that average means for each time $T',$ the BS implied vol $\sigma_{BS}(T',K) = average\Big[\sigma_{local}(S_i(T'))|S_i(0)=Spot,S_i(T)=K\Big]?$ here $i$ is the index of i-th path.

Comment: The x axis shows time (t) from now until expiration. The y axis show price S. Local volatility is a function of Price and (optionally) Time $\sigma_t=\sigma(t,S)$. Usually this function assigns low volatility to high prices and vice versa, which explains the labels *low volatility* and *high volatility* on the left of the figure.

Comment: @nbbo2 I updated understanding, am I correct?